# Problema con redux-saga y firebase al ejecutar un actions

Tags: firebase, react-native, redux, yield

Estoy intentando activar un action en la ejecución de una saga, el problema es que el Action nunca se activa, este es el código:

```
import firebase from 'react-native-firebase';

function authorize(query) {
  console.log(query.size);
  if(query.size){
    query.forEach(doc => {
      console.log(doc.data());
      put(loginActions.setLoginSuccess(doc.data()));
    });
  } else {
    put(loginActions.setError({ error: 'El usuario no existe' })); //Nunca se ejecuta esta acción
    return undefined;
  }
}

export function* loginFlow() {
  while (true) {
    const {username, password} = yield take(actions.LOGIN_ACTION);
    const ref = firebase.firestore().collection('usuarios');
    ref
    .where('email', "==", username)
    .where('contrasena', "==", password)
    .onSnapshot(authorize);
  }
}
```

La ejecución se lleva perfectamente hasta que llega el LoginAction.setError, no se ejecuta correctamente he hecho un console.log en el reducer, pero nunca entra. Supongo que debe haber otra forma de implementar y ejecutar el onSnapshot. Agradesco de antemano.